# How to implement 8b10b en/decoding protocol between two FPGAs?

Tags: serial, decoder, encoding, artix-series-fpga, kintex-series-fpga

I'm using two Xilinx FPGAs (one Kintex 7 and one Artix 7).  The Kintex 7 is tied to its own system (OPAL-RT software, it is a simulation software that is an addon to Simulink which lets data be output to an FPGA via a user CPU input) and will be outputting the its data as 10 serial bits.

The problem I am trying to solve is to send 20 serial bits (actually, 16 bits, but when it's encoded it should be 20, if I'm not mistaken) from the Kintex 7 to the Artix 7.

They will be clocked differently, but I thought the point of 8b10b was so that the clock of the primary FPGA can be recovered by the secondary  via the data stream.

Clearly I'm not very learned on the subject of setting up a communication link between two Xilinx FPGAs, but if someone has any insight that can help me, it would be super appreciated.

Worth noting is that I have access to Vivado/Xilinx System Generator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a "clock data recovery" (CDR) circuit. Your FPGA may include one as a hard core, if you are using signal rates in the gigabit-per-second range.

This function generally requires some specialized parts, such as a voltage-controlled oscillator (VCO) and an analog control circuit for the VCO, that aren't easily implemented in the FPGA fabric. So if you want to work at frequencies where the FPGA's hard cores don't work, you would need to purchase an external IC to do this function. You'd need to choose a data rate that is used commonly enough to make it worth building ICs to work there.

If you want to send this data at a relatively slow rate (say, below 50 Mb/s), you might want to use [Manchester encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manchester_code) instead of 8b/10b. With Manchester encoding, you can recover the clock from the data using a [simple circuit](http://www.cypress.com/blog/psoc-insiders-blog/manchester-code) requiring only a couple of gates, without needing a VCO or PLL. Your synthesis tool might not be happy about implementing this circuit, but at low data rates it should work just fine.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, @The_Photon. I think using Manchester coding seems like the way to go in this case.  What I would like to do is send at least 12 bits at time (since I have 12 MOSFET gates to control independently) and have the secondary FPGA decode these incoming 12 bits (in order) and send them properly. You think Manchester coding would work? We're working at switching frequencies of ~4kHz, so I think Manchester could work very well.

Comment: @Lerbi, yes, for 4 kbps, I would just use Manchester code. If you use 8b10b and a CDR you need to send some kind of signal continuously to keep the CDR locked. There is an "idle" word defined in 8b10b for this purpose. With Manchester you wouldn't need to send idles continuously but you might want to include some kind of start and stop bit framing so the receiver knows when a transmission starts and stops.

Comment: Thanks a lot, @The_Photon.  I'm starting to see some light at the end of the tunnel concerning the project.  With Manchester code, there seems to be a clock on the secondary FPGA. Is this necessary? Is there no way to have the FPGA just on its own, along with Vdd and GND, and have the incoming single supply both the clock and the data?

Comment: @Lerbi, in FGPA design you will need to get the incoming data onto the clock domain of your internal circuit somehow anyway.

Comment: Sorry, I hate to bother you further, but can you elaborate on what you mean?

Comment: Presumably after you get this data into your FPGA, you want to do something with it. You'll need to have it re-clocked onto the FPGA's internal clock domain to be able to do that. If you're trying to do fully combinatorial circuits in an FPGA, you're in for a world of pain, and ignoring well known best practices for FPGA design.

Comment: I guess what I'm wondering is... You can't use a subcircuit to recover the clock, and then run the flip flop/latch as well as the FPGA with that clock, and, in parallel with that, recovering the actual data from the stream? I suppose the issue comes with the delay in the recovery circuit.  So you recommend to have a dedicated clock for the secondary FPGA? I am using a test board that has a 100MHz oscillator (the primary FPGA also runs off 100MHz). So, this should work. I was just hoping to be able to use a standalone FPGA, but I suppose oscillators aren't exactly expensive.

Comment: If you're running an FPGA at 4 kHz, you're severely underutilizing the resources you paid for. Also, with the Manchester scheme, you'll stop getting more clock edges if no data is being sent (unless you go back to sending an idle signal when no data is available). Can you do all your processing on this data by the time the last data bit is clocked in?

Comment: I thought that with Manchester, you essentially XOR your data out with your clock signal, so there should always be switching?

Comment: @Lerbi, that depends if the transmitter continues to generate a clock when no data is present. You're free to design your system the best way you can to meet your requirements.

Comment: I see. Thanks a lot for your help... It's been the most progress I've made in a while for this project, since people around the university here aren't really well versed in digital systems (the ENGR department is quite new). There should always be data present with this set up, and I can XOR that data with the clock, so that may be what I do. Then I just need a recovery circuit on the secondary board to recover the clock, and then, in theory, I should be able to use that recovered clock in order to run that data retrieval?